# Plot points/circles on google map using python

Tags: python-2.7, google-maps, data-visualization, pygmaps

I am new to Python and I am trying to plot points(longitude,latitude) on google map in Python. I found a lib gmplot for the same but I am only able to draw drop pins instead I want to draw circles/points on the map. Could anybody show an example as for how to do it? I didn't find any example in StackOverflow.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the [github](https://github.com/vgm64/gmplot) page for this package. In their example they have the following;

```
gmap.plot(latitudes, longitudes, 'cornflowerblue', edge_width=10)
```

Replace 'latitudes' and 'longitudes' with arrays of the points you want.

I also saw in the code they have posted there a 'polygon' method, but the above was sufficient for what I needed.